# 連番の変数を作成するときの繰り返しをどうすればよろしいですか？

Tags: python

以下のようなコードで連番の変数（data0～2, x0～2, y0～2, Id0～2）を作りたいのですが、全て書いていくのが手間なのでfor文で書きたいと思っております。もう書いちゃってますが今後のために…

しかし、そのような連番の変数宣言を検索してもなかなか出てきません。

format関数で作成することも考えたのですが、文字列ではなく変数として宣言したいです。
そうするにはどのように行えばよろしいでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
data0 = data.loc[data['cluster'] == 0]
data1 = data.loc[data['cluster'] == 1]
data2 = data.loc[data['cluster'] == 2]

data0 = data0.reset_index(drop=True)
data1 = data1.reset_index(drop=True)
data2 = data2.reset_index(drop=True)

x0=data0['PCA1']
x1=data1['PCA1']
x2=data2['PCA1']
y0=data0['PCA2']
y1=data1['PCA2']
y2=data2['PCA2']
Id0=data0['ID']
Id1=data1['ID']
Id2=data2['ID']
```

Comment: (もうすでに解決済みのようですが、個人的には、同じような形の dataframe をいくつも宣言するより、それらを繋げた状態で持ち回す方が、最終的にコードは綺麗になるのではないか、と思っていたりなどします。)

Comment: 実のところ、[私の質問](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55567035/how-to-plot-annotations-on-every-axes-of-lmplot) でlmplotを使った書き方をしていたのですが、まだうまく行っておりません。そのため、それぞれのscatter plotをaxesごとに作成しようと思った次第です。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> for文で書きたい

記載されたコードに相当する内容を、リスト内包表記を活用することで以下のように書き換えることができます。

```
data_list = [data.loc[data['cluster'] == idx].reset_index(drop=True) for idx in range(3)]

xs = [d['PCA1'] for d in data_list]
ys = [d['PCA2'] for d in data_list]
Ids = [d['ID'] for d in data_list]
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！できました！リスト内のSeries参照に一瞬手間取りましたが、すぐ解決できたので問題なかったです。